# Apply length properties to lightning-combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

In SLDS there is a style for defining the [height of items in a Menu](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/menus/#Height), however, this property does not seem to be available in  the [lightning-combobox component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/specification), even though they use the class: `slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-10` by default.

Any advice on how to override this in LWC?

Comment: Hey Hii Jordan, did you find any way to define the height of the dropdown menu in combobox component in LWC ?